# How to filter data from firebase android studio

Tags: java, firebase

How to `filter` the retrieved data from **Firebase** in Android Studio?

I already stored the data in the Firebase and the data can be retrieved successfully, but I wanted to filter the data. I want the data to be displayed according to the phone number that have been entered.

This is the coding for `saving` the data into the firebase.

```
    Intent receiverIntent = getIntent();    
        String usersPhone = receiverIntent.getStringExtra("usersPhone");
        phoneid = usersPhone;
    private void SaveData() {
        String sugarlevel = SugarLevel.getText().toString();
        String date = edAnswerDate.getText().toString();
        String phone = phoneid;
        String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();

        User user = new User(sugarlevel, date, phone);
        databaseReference.child("data").child(id).setValue(user)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SugarLevel.this,"Data has been inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

This is the coding for `retrieving` the data.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlist);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleViewSugar);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data");
        Query query = databaseReference.child("data").orderByChild("phone").equalTo("id");
        query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapterSugarLevel = new MyAdapterSugarLevel(this,list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterSugarLevel);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    list.add(user);
                }
                adapterSugarLevel.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

This is the `constructor`.

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
    public class User {
    private String sugarlevel;
    private String date;
    private String phone;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String sugarlevel, String date, String phone) {
        this.sugarlevel = sugarlevel;
        this.date = date;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getSugarlevel() {
        return sugarlevel;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getPhone() { return phone; }
}
```

The JSON. file is as follow:

```
{
  "-NMXyWFEpifr-KviS_OW": {
    "date": "12 January 2023",
    "phone": "0124286945",
    "sugarlevel": "7.3"
  },
  "-NMXybQLylxpJW9WAFTV": {
    "date": "13 January 2023",
    "phone": "0124286945",
    "sugarlevel": "6.9"
  },
  "-NMXyjTp31tPBnKTX_vC": {
    "date": "14 January 2023",
    "phone": "0124286945",
    "sugarlevel": "6.7"
  },
  "-NMZahHd8IfixJqeCOxB": {
    "date": "23 December",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "sugarlevel": "6.6"
  },
  "-NMbxu12s7iGIpKUYwp2": {
    "date": "23 May",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "sugarlevel": "5.6"
  },
  "-NMc-Ji6ExvI7aEagS7Y": {
    "date": "22 May 2023",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "sugarlevel": "4.5"
  },
  "-NMc0zh_RZ4Yen6kVXxA": {
    "date": "23 May",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "sugarlevel": "5.6"
  },
  "-NMc2DD2EzmYq7U5BwW3": {
    "date": "29 April 2023",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "sugarlevel": "5.6"
  },
  "-NMdB933KuHzGIb6f8dG": {
    "date": "23 May",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "sugarlevel": "6.3"
  },
  "-NMhBOP4yhRK1lWaBrLJ": {
    "date": "26 March",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "sugarlevel": "6.2"
  },
  "-NMjLEQUiTYUCcP5LqSV": {
    "date": "13 May",
    "phone": "0124109549",
    "sugarlevel": "5.1"
  },
  "-NN0q3d2umBrb_7Ksqrk": {
    "date": "",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "sugarlevel": ""
  },
  "-NN3IW3nqlps-csG4w-O": {
    "date": "",
    "sugarlevel": ""
  },
  "-NN5L8b9IN3ZGAYxX7Yq": {
    "date": "27 January 2023",
    "phone": "0124109549",
    "sugarlevel": "4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Already insert it above.

Comment: Does those children exist directly under the root reference?

Comment: For now i am try to filter by phone, where it is the attribute in table named as data.

Comment: I cannot see any "table", but more correctly a node called `data`. Can please show that to us?